# How to prevent duplicate delivery in HornetQ

Tags: duplicates, hornetq

We have been studying HornetQ for a few weeks now.

In our business we have many "delta" messages, and (unfortunately...) they are not versionned (and since this is an international standard, they *will not* be versionned). This means that emitting the same message twice is frown upon, obviously. Still, the standard acknowledges it cannot really be avoided, and instruct the sender to flag the message as *possible duplicate* in this case.

I paged through HornetQ's documentation and it talks a lot about avoiding duplicating *received* by the server, but I could not find anything about avoiding *producing* duplicates.

To be clearer, suppose the following situation:

- 1 HQ server
- 1 Consumer

In the nominal scenario, the consumer takes a message in the queue, send it to a 3rd party, and upon receiving the acknowledgement, ack the message to the server so it is removed from the queue.

Now, the weak point here is the *ack* part. It is possible that the 3rd party received and processed the message but (for some reason) the ack fails and the message is *not* dequeued.

I realize it is not possible for HQ to know that the message has been fully delivered, however I would expect it to know that delivery was *already attempted* and that there is a distinct possibility that the message is going to be a duplicate *as far as the 3rd party is concerned*.

Is there any way for the Consumer to be informed about this *possibly already delivered* status so that it can flag the message appropriately ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to send a NAC (or throw back an error to HornetQ if the message was not acknowledged by the third party in the specified time period). If the queue in HornetQ has been configured with max-delivery-attempts > 0, then this will result in the message being redelivered.

At that point, the header of the message can be introspected by the HornetQ client  for the parameter "JMSXDeliveryCount" - this will indicate whether the message is being sent for the first time or it is being redelivered.

The methodology indicated here assumes that the HornetQ client uses the JMS API for consuming the messages. I'm sure there will also be something equivalent in the core API.

Comment: `JMSXDeliveryCount` great! I found the equivalent in the `ClientMessage` API: `getDeliveryCount`.